# Obtaining Brazilian Civil Registry documents from abroad

Tags: birth-records, marriage-records, brazil

I have located several birth and marriage records of interest in the Brazilian civil registry via familysearch.org; now I would like to obtain official copies and transcripts of these records. (I would also be interested in an *unofficial* transcription service. The handwriting on these records is extremely difficult to read.)

There seem to be many services for requesting copies and transcripts of Brazilian civil registry (RC) records, but so far I have not been able to find one that will accept payment from abroad and/or mail the documents internationally.

How do I obtain these records from abroad?

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining these records from abroad will be very difficult as you have to personally sign some papers (or ask an attorney to sign it in your behalf).

I recommend you to look for a lawyer's office on the city/region/state where the records you're requiring were emitted.